# Does this example implement the same as `ln -sr`?

Tags: ln

From coreutils' manual about `ln`

> `-r` `--relative`
>
> Make symbolic links relative to the link location.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> ln -srv /a/file /tmp
> ’/tmp/file’ -> ’../a/file’
> ```
>
> Relative symbolic links are generated based on their canonicalized
>   containing directory, and canonicalized targets. I.e., all symbolic
>   links in these file names will be resolved. See Section 18.5 [realpath
>   invocation], page 161, which gives greater control over relative fi le
>   name generation, as demonstrated in the following example:
>
> ```
> ln--relative() {
> test "$1" = --no-symlinks && { nosym=$1; shift; }
> target="$1";
> test -d "$2" && link="$2/." || link="$2"
> rtarget="$(realpath $nosym -m "$target" \
> --relative-to "$(dirname "$link")")"
> ln -s -v "$rtarget" "$link"
> }
> ```

Is the purpose of the example `ln--relative()` to implement the same as`ln -sr`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the shell-function `ln--remote` gives you a means to create relative symbolic links where the target path **will not** have symbolic-links resolved, which **by default** `ln -r` **would do**.

And it shows you how you could write a function, that uses more of the parameters of [`readpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/realpath-invocation.html#realpath-invocation) just in case you do need *even more* control over the output filename.